# Most Efficient way to Search Massive Redshift Table for Duplicate Values

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, duplicates, amazon-redshift

I have a large Redshift tables (hundreds of millions of ROWS with ~50 columns per row).

There is a need for me to find rows that have duplicate columns for a specific value.

Example:

if my table has the columns 'column_of_interest' and 'date_time', In those hundreds of millions of columns, I need to find all the instances where 'column_of_interest' has more than one value between a certain 'date_time'.

eg:

```
      column_of_interest  date_time
  ROW 1: ABCD-1234        165895896565
  ROW 2: FCEG-3434        165895896577
  ROW 3: ABCD-1234        165895986688
  ROW 4: ZZZZ-9999        165895986689
  ROW 5: ZZZZ-9999        165895987790
```

in the above.. since `ROW 1` and `ROW 3` have the same `column_of_interest` i would like that `column_of_interest` returned. and `ROW 4` and `ROW 5` as well, so i would like those returned.

So the end result would be:

```
duplicates
ABCD-1234
ZZZZ-9999
```

I have found a few things online, but the table is so large, the query times about before any results are returned. Am I going about this the wrong way? Here are a couple that I tried just to get the results back (but they timeout before returning).

```
SELECT column_of_interest, COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY column_of_interest
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
WHERE date_time >= 1601510400000 AND date_time < 1601596800000 
LIMIT 200

SELECT a.*
FROM my_table a
JOIN (SELECT column_of_interest, COUNT(*)
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY column_of_interest
HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
ON a.column_of_interest = b.column_of_interest
ORDER BY a.column_of_interest
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: WHERE should be before GROUP BY.

Comment: GAH!!! My tired eyes. that was it. Thanks for you help, jarlh.

Comment: So there are lots of unknowns in this question. 1) What time out value is being hit and how long is it? 2) What is the sort key(s) for the table and is it vacuumed and analyzed? 3) What is the distribution style and key of the table? 4) What is the size of the cluster? 5) Is the table in S3? Explain plan and actual execution info (from console) can really help narrow down what is taking time in your case. 100s of millions of rows is not large for Redshift - something is likely amiss here.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a fine method.  And it should not "time out".  Your version has a syntax error.

So try:

```
SELECT column_of_interest, COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
WHERE date_time >= 1601510400000 AND date_time < 1601596800000 
GROUP BY column_of_interest
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: So there are lots of unknowns in this question.  1) What time out value is being hit and how long is it?  2) What is the sort key(s) for the table and is it vacuumed and analyzed?  3) What is the distribution style and key of the table?  4) What is the size of the cluster?  5) Is the table in S3?

Explain plan and actual execution info (from console) can really help narrow down what is taking time in your case.  100s of millions of rows is not large for Redshift - something is likely amiss here.

Comment: @BillWeiner - you should probably put that comment on the question, not the answer.